# how to read from a file and turn it's contents to multiple variables in bash

Tags: bash, file, loops, variables

I have a file which has the following format :
1 a
2 b
3 c
 I want to loop through it, turning the second argument into a variable, and storing the first argument in that variable, for each line. 
 So in this case, create a variable 'a' and store 1 in it, create b and store 2 in it and so on. is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: What did you try so far? Please show us some effort.

Comment: `while read -r num char; do echo "number: $num" "character: $char"; done < file`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
while read line ; do
 Var=$(echo $line |awk '{print $2}')
 Value=$(echo $line |awk '{print $1}')
 export $Var=$Value
done < file

echo $a
echo $b
echo $c
```

Which produces:

```
> ./script.sh
1
2
3
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but could be greatly improved.

Comment: Thanks, while it works, I get a:   export: `=': not a valid identifier  error.
 If I remove the $ it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Use namerefs to perform indirect assignment.

```
while read -r value name; do
    declare -n var=name
     var=$value
done
declare +n var  # optional; makes var stop being a nameref
```

Prior to `bash` 4.3, you could use `declare` more generally (but a little more fragilely).

```
while read -r value name; do
    declare "$name=$var"
done < file
```